# sql code for firebird doesn't compile

Tags: sql, firebird

I am getting strange errors while trying to create a simple database using isql tools from the Firebird package.

The same code for creating a table works for other tables with other names.
I've tried with and without quotes surrounding fields and table names, no success.

It is Firebird 2.5 server version.

The code I'm trying to execute:

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;
SET NAMES UTF8;
CREATE DATABASE 'localhost:C:\fuzzdb.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;

CREATE TABLE RULES (
RULE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
IF_FUZZY SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_RULE_ID
PRIMARY KEY (RULE_ID),
);

CREATE TABLE VARS (
VAR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
VRULE_ID INTEGER,
INPOUTP SMALLINT,
RANGE_STRT INTEGER,
RANGE_END INTEGER,
VAR_NAME VARCHAR(40),
FUZ_SET INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT PK_VAR_ID
PRIMARY KEY (VAR_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FUZZSETS (
FS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
FS_NAME VARCHAR(40),
INPOUTP SMALLINT,
PAR1 FLOAT,
PAR2 FLOAT,
PAR3 FLOAT,
PAR4 FLOAT,
PAR5_HEDGE INTEGER,
FUZ_SET INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT PK_FS_ID
  PRIMARY KEY (FS_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FRULES (
FRULE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
RULE_ID INTEGER,
VAR_ID INTEGER,
FS_ID INTEGER,
INPOUTP SMALLINT,  
CONSTRAINT PK_FRULE_ID
PRIMARY KEY (FRULE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_RV (
LINK_RULES INTEGER,
LINK_VARS INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_RV
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_RULES, LINK_VARS)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_VARFS (
LINK_VRS INTEGER,
LINK_FS INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_VARFS
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_VRS, LINK_FS)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_RLVR (
LINK_RULE INTEGER NOT NULL,
LINK_VR INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_RLVR
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_RULE, LINK_VR)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_FRL_RL (      
LINK_FRULE INTEGER NOT NULL,
LINK_RULE INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FRL_RL
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_FRULE, LINK_RULE)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_FRL_VAR (
LINK_FRULE INTEGER NOT NULL,
LINK_VAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FRL_VAR
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_FRULE, LINK_VAR)
);

CREATE TABLE LINK_FRL_FS (
LINK_FSRULE INTEGER NOT NULL,
LINK_FS INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FRL_FS
PRIMARY KEY (LINK_FRULE, LINK_FS)
);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_FS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FSRULE
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_FSRULE)
REFERENCES FRULES(FRULE_ID);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_FS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FS
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_FS)
REFERENCES FUZZSETS(FS_ID);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_VAR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FRULE
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_FRULE)
REFERENCES FRULES(FRULE_ID);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_VAR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_VAR
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_VAR)
REFERENCES FUZZSETS(VAR_ID);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_RL
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_FRULE
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_FRULE)
REFERENCES FRULES(FRULE_ID);

ALTER TABLE LINK_FRL_RL
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LINK_RULE
FOREIGN KEY(LINK_RULE)
REFERENCES RULES(RULE_ID);

CREATE GENERATOR GEN_RULE_ID;
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_VAR_ID;
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_FS_ID;
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_FRULE_ID;

SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER BI_RULES FOR RULES
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.RULE_ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.RULE_ID = GEN_ID(GEN_RULE_ID, 1);
END^

CREATE TRIGGER BI_VARS FOR VARS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.VAR_ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.VAR_ID = GEN_ID(GEN_VAR_ID, 1);
END^

CREATE TRIGGER BI_FUZZSETS FOR FUZZSETS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.FS_ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.FS_ID = GEN_ID(GEN_FS_ID, 1);
END^

CREATE TRIGGER BI_FRULES FOR FRULES
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.FRULE_ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.FRULE_ID = GEN_ID(GEN_FRULE_ID, 1);
END^

SET TERM ; ^
COMMIT;
```

---

The output from the isql commmand:

```
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Token unknown - line 6, column 3
-)
At line 10 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-Unknown columns in index FK_LINK_FRL_FS
After line 82 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S02
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-LINK_FRL_FS
-At line 1, column 13.
After line 89 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S02
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-LINK_FRL_FS
-At line 1, column 13.
After line 94 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-could not find UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint in table FUZZSETS with specifie
d columns
After line 104 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S11
unsuccessful metadata update
-Index FK_LINK_FRULE already exists
After line 109 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-Table RULES not found
After line 114 in file c:\fdb.sql
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S02
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-RULES
-At line 1, column 29
At line 130 in file c:\fdb.sql
```

---

I don't get why it's impossible to create the first table "RULES" although the commands are similar to other tables.
Even without all the triggers and foreign keys (alter table..) I am getting at leaast the last error.
it says "Unknown columns in index FK_LINK_FRL_FS" but no mention of other similar indexing tables.

I am just starting working with databases and it could be that I missed or mixed something,
but I tried to compile with too many changes and still getting errors.
I've found more or less similar code here

http://sergworks.wordpress.com/category/firebird/

and I was able to compile it without problems.
Could somebody point me in the right direction or show how it is done in another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an unnessesary comma in the end of the PK constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_RULE_ID
PRIMARY KEY (RULE_ID),
```

So the parser expexts definition of field or constraint but it finds ")". Delete the comma and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. It removed one error, few others remained, but I've found out why. Will edit my original post in case somebody will need it